# Formatting multiple pictures in Office Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

How to select and format all pictures to

> Brightness 20%, Contrast -40% and Sharpness 100%

and select

> Wrapping Behind Text

in Word 2013 with few clicks?

Answer (score 1):

The re-do option can speed things up but is limited to one action at a time.

You could go and set the brightness to 20%. Click then on the next picture and use CTRL + Y. The second picture will now have 20% brightness too. And so on. It isn't perfect but saves clicks aplenty.

Comment: I can save one click more. Set brightness to 20% and click on the next picture and use F4. Searching for better solution. Thanks.